# Changing tab text and background color on selection

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to change the tab color and text when it get selected i have tried lots in both xml and android nothing working pls help i am extending with the Fragment and using tabpageradapter heres my code

```
public class BusTab extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_tab);

     TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
             public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());



            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};
            //Add New Tab

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("BUSNO").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("ROUTE").setTabListener(tabListener));

}
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use tab_indicator for each tab as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_tab_txt"
            style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/live"
            android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_underline_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabs_divider_view"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and drawable tab_text_color as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/dark_blue"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/dark_blue"/>
<item android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
```

and tab_underline_selector as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@color/dark_blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

and in your Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries_tabs, container, false);
    HorseRacesNowMainActivity.setHeaders(this);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    View tabIndicatorToday = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    ((TextView) tabIndicatorToday.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_txt)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.today));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.today)).setIndicator(tabIndicatorToday), EntriesTodayFragment.class, null);

    View tabIndicatorLive = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    ((TextView) tabIndicatorLive.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_txt)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.live));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.live)).setIndicator(tabIndicatorLive), EntriesLiveFragment.class, null);

    View tabIndicatorTrack = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    ((TextView) tabIndicatorTrack.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_txt)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.by_track));
    tabIndicatorTrack.findViewById(R.id.tabs_divider_view).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.by_track)).setIndicator(tabIndicatorTrack), EntriesTrackFragment.class, null);

    return view;
}
```